# MSM with separate add-ons enabled?

Tags: add-on, multi-site-manager

Can I have separate add-ons installed for each site when using MSM?

For instance, for an EE install using MSM:

- One or more sites within the EE install will use Transcribe for localization.
- One or more sites within the EE install will not have localization

If possible, I'd like to avoid having Transcribe enabled for a site with no localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the `exp_extensions`, `exp_fieldtypes`, or `exp_modules` tables have a `site_id` column, so no - enabled for one site is enabled for all sites.

But [Dom is right](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5170/55) - good add-ons will have *settings* per-site, which in most cases should prevent any issues with having add-ons enabled on sites where you don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

Addons are available to all sites in an MSM install, however they can have per-site preferences (that's up to the developer). Your best bet would probably be to contact the Transcribe devs to clarify the addon's MSM functionality and whether it's possible to have a mixture of localised and non-localised sites running from a single EE install.

Comment: Understood. My question was more "Can site A have matrix, transcribe and fiction module abc add-ons enabled, while Site B has matrix, seo and fiction module xyz add-ons enabled". Does that distinction make senes?

Comment: Addons are enabled globally and not on a per-site basis. Developers can build in code to enable site-specific features if they want to (and in theory this could include a per-site on/off switch), which is why I suggested contacting the Transcribe devs.